# pythonを使えばスマホからaiboを動かせますか？

Tags: api, aibo-developer

現状、ソニーさんのaiboビジュアルプログラミング(Scratch)は、スマホに対応していません。
そしてパソコンの側で実行させてる時しか有効ではないようです。
私のパソコンはデスクトップで２階に置いています。毎度aiboを２階に抱いて上がるといつか落としそうで怖いのです。しかしスマホなら、何処でも使えます。
そして、pythonでスマホのアプリを作れるそうですね？
ならば、pythonで組んだら、スマホからaiboを動かすことが出来るのでしょうか？
それとも、pythonでも、トークンとかdeviceIdとかが必要な場合、結局、自由にならないものなのでしょうか？

追記です。
例えば、AndroidにPydroidをインストールして、パソコンで組んだPythonのプログラムをダウンロードすれば、スマホからaibo を動かせないものでしょうか？
その場合、ユーザーは同じでもデバイスが違うということで無効でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo Web API は PC やサーバー、スマートフォンなど
インターネットにアクセス出来る任意のデバイスから実行が可能です。
デバイスによって実行可能な API の種類や実行内容に違いはありません。

Python で作成したプログラム（Python のファイル）をスマートフォンで実行する場合、
Python のプログラムが動く環境をスマートフォンに構築していただく必要があります。

なお、aibo Web API を実行する場合は、
お持ちの aibo の deviceId やトークンが必要になります。
deviceId やトークンはデバイスに依存しないため、
PC で使用したものをそのままスマートフォンでも使用できます。
トークンや deviceId については、下記の aibo デベロッパーサイトをご確認ください。
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: @aibo様、ありがとうございます！ スマホで使えると伺って、とても嬉しいです！ 私のスマホに、ソニーさんサイトから neural network console をダウンロード＆インストールしたのですが、neural network console で良かったのでしょうか？ Pydroid と比べて、どちらが簡単かも伺えると助かります。 トークンと deviceId は @tak様からご教示いただいて取得済みです。 stackoverflow でもaibo-developerタグでご回答頂きました。 現在、prog-8.com で勉強中です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

Neural Network Consoleは Deep Learning 用のツールであり
Python の開発環境ではないため、今回のお客様の用途には適していないと思われます。
また Pydroid は Python の開発環境のように思われますが、
私どもの製品ではないため動作確認などできておりません。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: コメントを受けて回答に追記したり改善したりする場合、回答を直接「編集」できますのでご検討くださいませ。基本的には、複数回答を投稿するのは本質的に異なる回答が複数ある場合です。スタック・オーバーフローは掲示板ではなく、wikiのようにQ&Aを逐次改善していく場所だと考えていただくと分かりやすいかと思います。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。